# geom_raster interpolation with log scale

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, raster, logarithm

I'm a bit stuck plotting a raster with a log scale. Consider this plot for example:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions)) +
 geom_raster(aes(fill = density))
```

[image]

But how to use a log scale with this geom? None of the usual methods are very satisfying:

```
 ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, log10(eruptions))) +
   geom_raster(aes(fill = density))
```

[image]

```
 ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, (eruptions))) +
   geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) + 
   scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

and this doesn't work at all:

```
 ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, (eruptions))) +
   geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) + 
   coord_trans(x="log10")
```

`Error: geom_raster only works with Cartesian coordinates`

Are there any options for using a log scale with a raster?

To be precise, I have three columns of data. The z value is the one I want to use to colour the raster, and it is not computed from the x and y values. So I need to supply all three columns to the `ggplot` function. For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 10), 
                  y = unlist(lapply(1:10, function(i) rep(i, 10))), 
                  z = faithfuld$density[1:100])

ggplot(dat, aes(x = log(x), y = y, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster()
```

[image]

What can I do to get rid of those gaps in the raster?

Note that this question is related to these two:

- [geom_raster interpolation with log scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866379/geom-raster-interpolation-with-log-scale)
- [Use R to recreate contour plot made in Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014676/use-r-to-recreate-contour-plot-made-in-igor/)

I have been keeping an updated gist of R code that combines details from the answers to these questions (example output included in the gist). That gist is here: https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/9a54cbd325149a8ff405

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dataset `faithfuld` already have a column for density which is the estimates of the 2D density for waiting and eruptions. You can find that the eruptions and waiting in the dataset are points in a grid. When you use `geom_raster`, it doesn't compute the density for you. Instead, it plots the density according to the x, y coordinates, in this case, is the grid. Hence, if you just apply the log transformation on y, it will distort the difference between y (originally they are equally spaced) and this is why you see the space in your plot. I used points to visualize the effects:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Use point to visualize the effect of log on the dataset
g1 <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(x=waiting, y=eruptions)) +
  geom_point(size=0.5)    

g2 <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(x=waiting, y=log(eruptions))) +
  geom_point(size=0.5)    

grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

If you really want to transform y to log scale and produce the density plot, you have to use the `faithful` dataset with `geom_density_2d`.

```
# Use geom_density_2d
ggplot(faithful, aes(x=waiting, y=log(eruptions))) +
  geom_density_2d() +
  stat_density_2d(geom="raster", aes(fill=..density..),
                  contour=FALSE)
```

[image]

**Update: Use `geom_rect` and supply custom xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax values to fit the spaces of the log scale.**

Since the `geom_raster` use the same size of tiles, you probably have to use `geom_tile` or `geom_rect` to create the plot. My idea is to calculate how large (width) each tile should be and adjust the `xmin` and `xmax` for each tile to fill up the gap.

```
 dat <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 10), 
                  y = unlist(lapply(1:10, function(i) rep(i, 10))), 
                  z = faithfuld$density[1:100])
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)   

g <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = log(x), y = y, fill = z)) +
  geom_raster()   

# Replace the ymin and ymax
distance <- diff((unique(dat$x)))/2
upper <- (unique(dat$x)) + c(distance, distance[length(distance)])
lower <- (unique(dat$x)) - c(distance[1], distance) 

# Create xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
dat$xmin <- dat$x - 0.5 # default of geom_raster is 0.5
dat$xmax <- dat$x + 0.5
dat$ymin <- unlist(lapply(lower, function(i) rep(i, rle(dat$y)$lengths[1])))
dat$ymax <- unlist(lapply(upper, function(i) rep(i, rle(dat$y)$lengths[1])))        

# You can also use geom_tile with the width argument
g2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=log(x), y=y, xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, fill=z)) +
  geom_rect() 

# show the plots     
grid.arrange(g, g2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, In my actual use-case I really need to use a third variable as the density, as in the `faithfuld` dataset, so your suggestion doesn't solve my problem. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "really need to use the third variable as the density.". Do you have a way to calculate the density? Another approach is to retrieve the data which `ggplot` use to construct the plot. You can save the plot as an object like `g` and retrieve the data by `ggplot_build(g)$data`. The data contains the density.

Comment: Or can you edit the problem and provide a subset of your actual use-case?

Comment: I mean that I have three columns in my dataset, and the z column is not computed from the x or y columns. I have another way to compute the z value, independent of the plotting function. I want to use the z column as the colour values for the raster.

Comment: Thanks for your update, that solves my problem. I've edited your answer to make your solution more general (and suitable for my actual use-case).

Comment: Your last plot is an exceptionally useful case for creating surface plots for sparsely populated data. In order to cater for x data that is not uniformly populated I changed your code for my use case so that there is distance, upper and lower variables for both X and Y and then updated the xmin and xmin formulas to look the same as ymin and ymax. Thus creating a completely dynamic method for any data set regardless of the spacing between x and y variables